How can I create a new folder on macOS using a shell command in SwiftUI macOS while ensuring compatibility with the App Sandbox and using bookmarks?
The app is designed to allow the user to select a directory using NSOpenPanel, save access permissions via a security-scoped bookmark, and create a folder in the selected directory using the mkdir bash command executed with Process. The security-scoped bookmark ensures the app can access the directory even after the user closes the app or in subsequent sessions.
However, the code does not work when the App Sandbox is enabled. When the sandbox is removed, the folder creation works without issues. Despite using a security-scoped bookmark to resolve the directory path and access the folder, the app still encounters an "Operation not permitted" error. This indicates that the sandbox restrictions prevent the bash command from operating on the directory, even though permissions should theoretically have been granted via the bookmark.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var folderName: String = ""
    @State private var bookmarkData: Data? = nil
    @State private var errorMessage: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            TextField("Enter folder name", text: $folderName)
                //.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            
            Button("Choose Desktop Folder") {
                chooseDesktopFolder()
            }
            
            Button("Create Folder") {
                createFolder()
            }
            .disabled(bookmarkData == nil || folderName.isEmpty)
            
            if let errorMessage = errorMessage {
                Text(errorMessage)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 400, height: 200)
    }
    
    private func chooseDesktopFolder() {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        openPanel.prompt = "Select Folder"
        
        openPanel.begin { response in
            if response == .OK, let selectedURL = openPanel.url {
                do {
                    // Create a bookmark from the selected URL
                    let bookmark = try selectedURL.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
                    self.bookmarkData = bookmark
                    self.errorMessage = "Folder selected successfully."
                } catch {
                    self.errorMessage = "Failed to create bookmark: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                }
            } else {
                self.errorMessage = "No folder selected."
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func createFolder() {
        guard let bookmarkData = bookmarkData else {
            errorMessage = "No folder selected."
            return
        }
        
        do {
            // Resolve the bookmark to get the folder URL
            var isStale = false
            let folderURL = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, options: .withSecurityScope, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
            
            // Start accessing the security-scoped resource
            guard folderURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
                errorMessage = "Failed to access folder."
                return
            }
            
            defer { folderURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
            
            // Construct the path of the new folder
            let newFolderURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent(folderName)
            
            // Use bash command to create the folder
            let process = Process()
            process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/mkdir")
            process.arguments = [newFolderURL.path]
            
            try process.run()
            process.waitUntilExit()
            
            if process.terminationStatus == 0 {
                errorMessage = "Folder created successfully."
            } else {
                errorMessage = "Failed to create folder with mkdir command."
            }
        } catch {
            errorMessage = "Error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
        }
    }
}


Thanks, making a folder with bash is just a test, I have other things to do. It is more like testing bash with swift and swiftui

From this, your app can only run bash scripts in a specific directory, and only the user can copy scripts to that directory. So in general this is not possible, but if you be more specific about the things you want to do, there might be an alternative.

The app I want to create will make adjustments that require using Bash commands in the terminal. For example, we can customize system settings, like altering the Dock's appearance, enabling or disabling transparency effects, or even changing Finder's behavior—all through simple console commands.

Is Bash — or any other shell — relevant here at all? It seems that what you actually want is to execute programs with arguments? (Not sure if this makes any difference in practice, but eliminating the shell from the question should reduce the confusion space a bit.)

Since you are accessing the selected files under SIP with write permission, make sure you had enable the read/write permission in the entitlement.
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

In Xcode, it's <your-target> -> Signing & Capabilities -> App Sandbox -> File Access, check the option Read/Write for User Selected Files.
